# Back button works as if I am signed in even after logout

Tags: java, liferay, back

I am having an issue with `Liferay`, when I click the <kbd>back</kbd> button on browser after logging out, it gets back to the page as if I am logged in. But when i try to access anything in the page, then it refers to Sign in.

I think I need to clear the cache header. Did anyone had this issue before? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your Session is not getting destroyed when you are logging out. Are you calling `/c/portal/logout` ? This will invoke `sessionDestroyed` method.

If you are having a customized logout link in your Portal, make sure it calls `/c/portal/logout/`

Comment: it calls `/c/portal/logout/` still the result is same.

Comment: What is the logout page you have configured in Admin port?

Comment: I have not customized logout link.

Comment: Please check by configuring the Default Landing Page and Default Logout page in Admin port. In Liferay 6 on wards, specifying Landing and Loguot page in Admin port is required.